# phpmailer has authentcation problems

Tags: php

I have this error with my `Authentication unsuccessful`, and I can't seem to find why I can't sent a mail. To me everything looks good, but I can't find this error.

[image: Authentication unsuccessful]

My php code:

```php
<?php
    require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail ->IsSmtp();
    $mail ->SMTPDebug = 2;    
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
    );
    $mail ->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail ->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail ->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
    $mail ->Port = 587; // or 587
    $mail ->IsHTML(true);
    $mail ->Username = "test@xxx.com";
    $mail ->Password = "xxxx";
    $mail ->SetFrom("test@xxx.com");
    $mail ->FromName = "From";
    $mail ->Subject = "Prueba con PHPMailer";
    $mail ->Body = "<H3>Bienvenido! Esto Funciona!</H3>";
    $mail ->AddAddress("test@xxxx.com");
    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
        echo "<br>Mail Not Sent<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br>Mail Sent<br>";
    }
?>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: there can be some issue with your username and password.

Comment: Well i enter the login i use for `https://outlook.live.com/`, and they are the same.

Comment: which PHP mailer version are you using?

Comment: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzlVPBUP5IM8dmpDZ2tEZjdRaEU/view`, and it says: `5.2.15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for outlook:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth= true;
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username= $account;
$mail->Password= $password;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName= $from_name;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $msg;
$mail->addAddress($to);
```

Change variable with you access, for XAMPP config : [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sending_emails.htm)

Comment: I'm still getting the same `Authentication unsuccessful` ERROR.

Comment: Have you try to local server or online?

Comment: What do you mean? my host and port is `smtp.live.com` and `587`? So i guess it's online? or am i wrong?

Comment: No, i mean if you test it to local server like XAMPP or in a web server

Comment: Yeah i use `XAMPP`

Comment: So we have find the problem, is XAMPP the "problem", try you code online you will see the code work - edit answer with XAMPP config link

Comment: How do you suggest i do that? the XAMPP is run on a server, and i access all the php files from my `domain.com/phpfile.php`

Comment: Can you open free domain with free space and try it there, or use link i wrote for change setting of xampp

Comment: Man i love you!! When you wrote that, i was like ooh wait.... I think i forgot to change my `[mail function]` in `php.ini` and when i changed that to the right host/port the mail sent smooth!